# Hiding WinForm for 2 mins then showing it again in a loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a form which I made in VB.NET I am populating fields on that form and showing it to the user in a `For Each...Next` loop.

It basically has a `PictureBox` which acts like a *Close* button - I'm trapping the click event to close the form.

However I now want to give the user the option to be able to click the dummy Close button, and KEEP the form closed for 2 minutes (i.e. pause execution for 2 minutes..because what if the user clicked in the middle of the loop?)...and then as soon as the 2 minutes are up I want the form to display with the next iteration of data.

Is this possible?

I'm posting some sample code of my program:

```
For intI As Integer = 0 To dvNotifications.Count - 1
    //Just population some normal fields here...
    Dim CustomNotification As New CustomNotification
    CustomNotification.lblSubject.Text = IIf(strSubject = String.Empty, "[No Subject]", strSubject)

    CustomNotification.ShowDialog() 'Just before the next iteration I show the form...
Next
```

Comment: This is not c#. It is hard to understand what you want to do. But you can use `TImer`

Comment: This looks like VBA code.  Please replace the C# tag with VBA tag if that is correct.

Comment: @T.S I'm showing that form in a loop, basically a fade in fade out effect to show to my user in the Notification Area. The loop runs 10 iterations (i.e. there are 10 events I want to show my user). I want the user to have the ability to close the bluff `X` which is a picture box and keep the form closed for 2 mins, but I want to Show the form again without losing my place in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can use timer (written in c# because your original tag was c#)

```cs
class FormController
{
    private Timer _timer = new Timer();
    private MyForm _form;

    private void StartForm()
    {
        if (_form == null)
            _form = new MyForm(_timer);
        f.Show();
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        StartForm();
    }

}


// Your form shows and does something like this
// In your form

class MyForm
{
    private Timer _timer;

    private void OnFormClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Interval = 120000; //ms
        _timer.Start();
    }

}
```

Of course, you will need to wire up all the events, etc. But this should give you an idea how it works.

In this code form will be closed [destroyed/disposed] and new one will be created every time. If you want to keep this same instance, you will use form `Show/Hide`, and then the code that I have on `OnFormClosing` will be on `OnVisibileChanged` instead

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what would the `timerCallback` be?

Comment: @RahulKishore I forgot to remove it - it was part of the original idea

Comment: Ahh, this looks better now! Thanks, I'll have a play with it and see what happens.

Comment: @RahulKishore Just one comment: in this code form will be closed [destroyed] and new one will be created every time. If you want to keep this same instance, you will use form `Show/Hide`, and then the code that I have on `OnFormClosing` will be on `OnVisibileChanged` instead.

Comment: Used an simple Timer and saving of 2 date times to solve this. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @RahulKishore Timer and 2 `dateTime` - sounds like overkill